# softaculous installation of orangehrm error

Tags: orangehrm, softaculous

When using Softaculous on Plesk to install OrangeHRM, it goes to about 5% and then stops with the error "Unable to fetch the required data hence can not install OrangeHRM"

I have checked the prerequisites and all are ok.  I've also tried a manual installation, but after uploading the files to the subdomain, when I try and access [www.sub.domain/orangehrm-5.5](http://www.sub.domain/orangehrm-5.5) I get server error 500.  I have other apps installed on other subdomains on the same server and all work fine.